# why cucumber cases always runs in my CI even I set the tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a rails application.
And all tests are run by Jenkins and controlled by rake tasks.
I set the cucumber.yml to make sure wip taged cases and acc tags cases never run without that environment variables.
I run them locally by cucumber. It works well.
However, when I run them in jenkins. 
It is likely the setting does not work.

The cucumber.yml is like this:

```
    <%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip --tags ~@acc"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip" if ENV["ACC"]
parallel_opts = %{
  --format pretty
  --format junit --out features/reports/junit
  --format json  --out features/reports/#{ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER']||1}_report.json
  --strict
  --tags ~@wip
}

%>
parallel: <%= parallel_opts %> features
default: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, the parallel_opts are not set correctly.